# load image from cache in volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley, image-caching

I use volley to load image and cache image in android . I want to load image from cache when cache has requested image .So I set my image view with below method.

```
public void setImage(String url)
{
    final ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    img_thumb.setImageBitmap(response);
                }
            }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //img_thumb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(imgRequest);

}
```

but I don't know how to load from cache when that image is available from cache?

Answer (score 0):

Volley will automatically pull the bitmap from the cache when triggering an image request, provided you supplied the `ImageLoader` you created with a valid `ImageCache` object:

```
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(CACHE_SIZE);

        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mMemCache.get(url);
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mMemCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Then, to load images, use the `ImageLoader` you created:

```
/**
 * Performs a request to load an image from a given url.
 * @param url the url to load the image from.
 * @param listener the listener which will receive a call once the image load finishes (either with success or failure). The listener is called on the UI thread.
 * @param maxWidth the max width (in pixels) of the requested image. The returned bitmap will not exceed this width. Use 0 for unlimited
 * @param maxHeight the max height (in pixels) of the requested image. The returned bitmap will not exceed this height. Use 0 for unlimited.
 * @return an ImageContainer object which can be used to access the bitmap once the request has completed, or to cancel the request before it completes.
 */
public ImageLoader.ImageContainer loadImageFromUrl(final String url, final ImageRequestListener listener, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {


    if (url == null || Uri.parse(url) == null || Uri.parse(url).getHost() == null) {
        Logger.e("VolleyManager: loadImageFromUrl: invalid url " + url);
        listener.onImageLoadFailed();
        return null;
    }

    return mImageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            if (listener != null && response.getBitmap() != null) {
                listener.onImageLoadComplete(response.getBitmap());
            } else if (listener != null) {
                listener.onImageLoadFailed(;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onImageLoadFailed();
            }
        }
    }, maxWidth, maxHeight);
```

Comment: thanks,please check my 2nd answer. how can i integrate your code with my code ?

Comment: Just use the loadimagefromurl method

Comment: what is ImageRequestListener?how can i use this method

Comment: this is just an interface I created, you can alter it to suit your needs.

Comment: do you have any complete sample which explain Volley image caching and loading from cache with detail? I read a lot but i can not still cache any image .i'm so confused